# Symfony2 Load content based on device used with LiipThemeBundle

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I need to make my controller load a different skin with the information based on the device it is being used with. I can load the templates with LiipBundle. I wonder if I can load the content something like that too?? For example this is my controller:

```
public function mainAction() {


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $skins = $em->getRepository('MediaparkLtSkinBundle:Skin')->findOneBy( array('id' => 1));

    return $this->render('MediaparkLtMainBundle:Main:main.html.twig', array('skin' => $skins));

    return array();
}
```

right now this just loads the skin with the id 1 on the theme. I need to make an if statement and check if user is on desktop, if so then load this theme with this skin... How can I do that??? Here is the idea:

```
 public function mainAction() {

        (if using desktop) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $skins = $em->getRepository('MediaparkLtSkinBundle:Skin')->findOneBy( array('id' => 1));

        return $this->render('MediaparkLtMainBundle:Main:main.html.twig', array('skin' => $skins));
        }

        else {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $skins = $em->getRepository('MediaparkLtSkinBundle:Skin')->findOneBy( array('id' => 2));

            return $this->render('MediaparkLtMainBundle:Phone:Phonemain.html.twig', array('skin' => $skins));

        }

        return array();
    }
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the user agent to see if there are any indications of mobile. [Or search for a library that does this](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20detect%20mobile).

see $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']